# Test mocked service in controller in symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony, testing, mocking, symfony4

I would like to test this controller on my symfony 4.4 project :

```
final class WebhookController extends AbstractController
{
    private CustomLoggerService $customLogger;
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private MyService $myService;
    private UserMailer $userMailer;
    private AdminMailer $adminMailer;

    public function __construct
    (
        CustomLoggerService $customLogger,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        MyService $myService,
        UserMailer $userMailer,
        AdminMailer $adminMailer
    )
    {
        $this->customLogger = $customLogger;
        $this->myService = $myService;
        $this->userMailer = $userMailer;
        $this->adminMailer = $adminMailer;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/webhook/new", name="webhook_new")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function new(Request $request)
    {
        $uri = $request->getUri();
        $this->customLogger->info("new event uri ".$uri);
        $query = $request->query->all();
        if(isset($query['RessourceId']))
        {
            //infos
            $id = $query['RessourceId'];
            $event = $this->myService->getInfos($id);
            $infoId = $event->infoId;
            $this->customLogger->info("new info id ".$infoId);

            $userRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
            $user = $userRepo->findOneByEventUserId((int)$event->owners[0]);

            //mail sent
            $this->userMailer->sendAdminEvent($event, $user);
            $this->customLogger->info("new mail sent");

        }
        else
        {
            $this->adminMailer->sendSimpleMessageToAdmin("no ressource id", "no ressource id");
        }
        return new JsonResponse();
    }
}
```

I need to mock MyService because it calls an external API

Here my test :

```
class WebhookControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    use LoginTrait;

    public function testNewPayinIRessourceIdExists()
    {
        self::ensureKernelShutdown();
        /** @var KernelBrowser $client */
        $client = $this->startClient();
        $client->enableProfiler();

        $myService = $this->createMock(MyService::class);
        $myService->expects($this->once())->method("getInfos")->willReturn([
            [
                'hi'=>'hi'
            ]
        ]);


        // if I do this, I can't inject my mocked service
        $client->request('GET', '/webhook/new/?RessourceId=1111');
        
       // if I do this, I can't autowire all my dependencies of my controller
       $controller = new WebhookController(xxxx);
       $controller->new(xxx);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to test my controller ? If I do `new WebhookController(xxxx)` I have a lot of dependencies which need other dependencies and it's not maintenable.
Or I should move the customlog and sending emails in other service and keep the controller without these dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate the controller by yourself.

You can make service that you need to mock public for test environment, create mock and override in the container.

1. In `config/services_test.yaml` add following config

   ```yaml
   App\Service\MyService:
     public: true
   ```
2. Mock service

   ```php
   $myService = $this->createMock(MyService::class);
   $myService->expects($this->once())->method("getInfos")->willReturn([
       [
           'hi'=>'hi'
       ]
   ]);
   self::$container->set(MyService::class, $myService);
   ```
3. And make HTTP request

   ```php
   $client->request('GET', '/webhook/new/?RessourceId=1111');
   ```

Comment: thanks @greeflas I didn't know  this :)  I tried but I can't do what I want. When I use this technique, ```$myService->getInfos(1111)``` in my test returns my correct object but in test, my controller tested still wants use the API and try to connect it and use the real method and not my mock. Seems the mock isn't passed to the controller. Do you see why? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What I changed, I don't know if add arguments is the problem

```services:
  App\Service\MyService:
    arguments:
      $myParameters: '%my_parameters%'
    public: true```

Comment: Could you try `static::$kernel->getContainer()->set(MyService::class, $myService)`? It should be the same container as inside controller.

Comment: I tried ```$client->getContainer()->set(MyService::class, $myService);```
        and ```self::$container->set(MyService::class, $myService);```
        and ```static::$kernel->getContainer()->set(MyService::class, $myService)``` none of them worked :/

Comment: I created POC application https://github.com/greeflas/Symfony_tests_mock_POC.
It should help you in investigation.

Comment: wow thanks a lot !!! your example is working in my environment so... I don't know why I have this problem. I will continue my investigation thanks :)

Comment: I finally succeeded, thanks for your time :)

Comment: @misterdebug what was the issue? Do we need to update my answer?

Comment: I had a lot of strange bugs like ```$client->request('GET', '/webhook/new/?RessourceId=1111');``` is not working but ```$client->request('GET', '/webhook/new?RessourceId=1111');``` yes

Comment: strange issue with kernel and doctrine too but now it's ok